# Apply decimal formatting for a decimal in a sentence of strings + numbers

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, string-formatting

I am trying to apply decimal formatting for a decimal in a string sentence
`(The temperature of $place is $value degree $unit)` which is converted into `(The temperature of room is 45 degree Celsius)`

I am using python's Template library with `safe_substitute` method to change my string para-metered contents. 
I need to format one of the decimal values (the `$value` from the above sentence) in the same sentence with specific format (`{0:.2f}`). Any ideas on how to do this, pls respond.

Comment: Why don't you use `str.format`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `format` to control how many decimal you want to show in `safe_substitute` as following:

```
from string import Template
s = Template('(The temperature of $place is $value degree $unit)')
print(s.safe_substitute(place='room', value='{:.2f}'.format(45), unit='Celsius'))
```